# How to copy js object that contains function

Tags: javascript

I have issues with copying my object that has a function in itself. see below code and afterwards explanation of issue.

```
const obj1 = {...object1};
const obj2 = {...object2};
const obj3 = {...object3};

const parentObj = {
 id: "123",
 name: "foo",
 nestedObj: [obj1, obj2, obj3],
somefunc(){
 return obj1.value + obj2.value + obj3.value
}
}
```

My way of copying this object...

```
 const copyObj = {
...parentObj,
nestedObj: parentObj.nestedObj.map(obj=>{
 return{
  ...obj
}
})
}
```

The issue with above is the following:

1. I have a form-control that allows me to change obj1, obj2 or obj3 value key.
2. This "new" value that is being assigned to the nested object, is needed for the function.
3. However when being copied, my function is always using the original value of the nestedObj.

Is there a way for me to bind the function the the newly copied parentObj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `somefunc` is called like `copyObj.somefunc()` such that the `this` value corresponds to the object you call the method on, then it will work when you define `somefunc` as follows:

```
  somefunc(){
    return this.nestedObj.reduce((sum, obj) => sum + obj.value, 0);
  }
```

So if now `nestedObj` has the objects you really want to use, then `somefunc` will produce the expected sum, provided it is called on the right container object.

Comment: It was actually me not using the "this" keyword that caused the issue. Thank you for your support, much appreciated!